# Error with Formatted String as DateTime in EditItemTemplate in DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-formatting, datalist, datetime-format

I have a `DataList` bound to a table containing a `DateTime` field.  The `ItemTemplate` `Label` works great (and shows date of `12/02/2011`) but I get an error when I try to set the `Text` property of the `TextBox` in the Edit template.

The error I get when rebinding is this :

**The string was not recognized as a valid `DateTime`. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.**

```
protected void dlDistributions_EditCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    dlDistributions.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
    dlDistributions.DataBind();   // <-- error occurs here 
}
```

The simplified `DataList` is below:

```
<DataList Id="dlDistributions" OnEditCommand="dlDistributions_EditCommand" >
<ItemTemplate>
    Start Date:
    <asp:Label ID="lblStartDate" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval('StartDate', "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>" />
    <br />
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
   Start Date:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StartDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' />
    <br />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

How can I avoid the error to format the `DateTime` field BEFORE it tries to bind itself to the `TextBox` control in the `EditTemplate`?

Thanks!

Comment: I found my own problem : one of the child objects of my object called Distributions had a LinqDataSource on the same page that was trying to order by a DateTime.  As the datetime was returned as an Object(not a DateTime) the sort was breaking.  So the line of actual error was elsewhere on the page.